# insert table into <li> when using jsTree & json

Tags: html, json, jstree

Can I somehow insert a **table** inside `<li>` when using

- jsTree (1.0) and
- json?

let's say in this code where I want to insert **table** for

- both node and
- leaf.

Why? To display more things than only a name and using nice formatting.

```
                "data" : [
                    {
                        "data" : "A node",
                        "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]
                    },
                    {
                        "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id" },
                        "data" : {
                            "title" : "Long format demo",
                            "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                 }
                    }
                ]
```

update:

it seems to me that I can use `html_titles`. But could somebody give me an example how to insert whole table and get cell data from variables?

### Update2:

whether I use

```
"data" : "<table><tr><td>Site name</td><td>variable 1</td><td>variable 2</td></tr></table>",
```

or

```
"title" : "<table><tr><td>Site name</td><td>variable 1</td><td>variable 2</td></tr></table",
```

the table is placed on a new line. Not **next to the tree icon**. Can I fix that somehow?

Comment: I imagine you can use CSS to position the table next to the tree icon. If you want some help with that, post the generated markup and existing CSS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on the original post to help others trying to do the same:

```
$(function () {
$("#demo1").jstree({ 
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : [
            { 
                "data" : "<table style='display: inline-block'><tr><td>Site name</td><td>variable 1</td><td>variable 2</td></tr></table>", 
                "children" : [ "Child 1", "Child 2" ]
            },
            { 
                "attr" : { "id" : "li.node.id" }, 
                "data" : { 
                    "title" : "Long format demo", 
                    "attr" : { "href" : "#" } 
                } 
            }
        ]
    },
    "core" : {"html_titles" : true},
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data" ]
});
```

});

The key is to allow html in the titles which is set in the core options as well as the table style

Answer (score 1):

I thought it needs to be solved on javascript level but `<table  style='display: inline-block'>` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

**Addon**: The "text" you supply is actually treated as html by default.

```
core: {
  data: [{
    id: "ID",
    parent: "#",
    text: "<span>Individual</span>",
    icon: 'fa fa-star text-warning'
  },}]}
```