# Modify DOM of created node in jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to modify the DOM jstree creates when creating a node. When creating a node programmatically jstree creates 
    `<li><a ../></li>`.
I want to wrap the  into a `<span><a ../> more content</span>` but I've no idea how to customize the DOM jstree creates.

Creation of the initial jstree is straightforward (with some dummy data):

```
$("#tree").jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "data": {
                "data": "TE-CON",
                "metadata": {
                    "id": 23
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "data": "Node 1",
                        "children": [ "Node1.1", "Node1.2" ]
                    },
                    "TE-CON"
                ]

            }},
        "plugins": [ "themes", "json_data", "grid" ]
    });
```

This creates a DOM:

```
<li class="jstree-last jstree-open">
<ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
    <a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon"></ins>TE-CON</a>

    <ul style="">
        <li class="jstree-open">
            etc...
```

Rather than the `<a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon"></ins>TE-CON</a>` which is created I want to have a `<span><a href="#"><ins class="jstree-icon"></ins>TE-CON</a></span>` with some more additional HTML in the span block.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @Kay added the code and result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the same way as you mentioned In case you have created an element statically from the server. However if you have created the element dynamically, you have to perform the operation after the node is created like this:

```
var node = $.jstree._reference('#demo1').create_node(
 node, 'last', data, false, false
);
var newnode = node.children().last();

node.append('<input type="text" ></input>');
```

There is another way is to use html_titles as per this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5059969/2547372